# What is the proper way to set SELinux context in an RPM .spec?

Tags: compiling, rpm, selinux

I am trying to build an RPM that targets RHEL4 and 5. Right now I call `chcon` from `%post` but multiple Google entries say "that's not how you are supposed to do it" with very limited help on the *right* way. I've also noticed that `fixfiles -R mypackage check` says the files are wrong when they are right (as expected; the RPM DB doesn't realize what I want)..

- I specifically say RHEL4 because it does *not* have `semanage` which seems to be one of the proper ways to do it. (Add a new policy and then run `restorecon` on your directories in `%post`.)

  - I also don't need my own context, just `httpd_cache_t` on a non-standard directory.
- I have also seen "let `cpio` take care of it" - but then I have a new problem that a non-root RPM building user cannot run `chcon` on the build directories. I cheated and had `sudo` in the spec file but that didn't seem to matter anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Fedora Packaging Guidelines](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingDrafts/SELinux#File_contexts) have a draft document explaining how to handle SELinux in packages, and they use `semanage`.  Without `semanage`, it looks like supporting RHEL 4 is going to be a hack, and there's no way around that.

According to the [rpm 4.9.0 release notes](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.9.0#SELinuxpolicies), there has been some support directly in rpm for managing SELinux policies, but it has historically been broken:

> - Older versions of RPM supported a %policy directive in spec for attaching SELinux policies into the package header, but this was never really usable for anything. Any uses of the %policy directive in specs should be removed as this unused directive prevents building with RPM 4.9.0 and later, while not doing anything for older versions.
> - Starting with RPM 4.9.0, SELinux policy packaging is supported via new %sepolicy section in the spec. Such packages cannot be built, but are installable on older RPM versions too (but the included policies will not be used in any way).

I see no mention of file contexts there, and I haven't been able to find any mention of direct file context support (like `%attr` in the `%files` section).  In any case, it looks like RHEL 6 is only on rpm 4.8.0, so (unless I've missed something) the `semanage` route is as good as we're going to be able to do at least until RHEL 7.